# how to send email when condition is met on spreedsheet upon submit the form

Tags: google-sheets

my spreedsheet, in column B contains countries name. i want to know when people from a country (e.g France) fills the form and choose  a (France)  as their country name. may i know the necessary code for this case?

Comment: How does your question title relate to the body of your question?